# How to update two tables using single procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have to tables as **Supplier** and **Item** in a database created for a company. Both tables have a column as **Qty** to store the quantities that each suppliers has and item quantity owned by the company. I want write a procedure to increase the qty in table **Item** and at the same time decrease that amount form the table **Suppler**. This will be done for a selected supplier and a item type. I have write the procedure as below.

```
PROCEDURE Increase_Supplier_Part_Project_Quantity(
   supplier_id_ IN NUMBER, part_id_ IN NUMBER, project_id_ IN NUMBER, qty_ IN NUMBER)
IS
   
   CURSOR get_record IS
      SELECT *
      FROM Supplier_Part_Project_Tab p1, Supplier_Part_Tab p2
      WHERE p1.Supplier_Id =supplier_id_ AND p1.Part_Id = part_id_ AND p1.Project_Id = 
      project_id_ AND p2.Supplier_Id =supplier_id_ AND p2.Part_Id = part_id_;
  
BEGIN
   OPEN get_record;
   IF get_record%NOTFOUND THEN
      dbms_output.Put_Line('No Record found');
   END IF;
  
   UPDATE Supplier_Part_Project_Tab
   SET Quantity = Quantity + qty_
   WHERE Supplier_Id =supplier_id_ AND Part_Id = part_id_ AND Project_Id = project_id_;
  
   UPDATE Supplier_Part_Tab
   SET Quantity = Quantity - qty_
   WHERE Supplier_Id =supplier_id_ AND Part_Id = part_id_;
  
   dbms_output.put_line('Record UPDATED');
   CLOSE get_record;
  
END Increase_Supplier_Part_Project_Quantity;
```

But I think I have done some mistakes in it. Can anyone please help me to identify the mistakes I have done?

Answer (score 1):

Read comments within code.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_isppq(
  2    supplier_id_  IN  NUMBER,
  3    part_id_      IN  NUMBER,
  4    project_id_   IN  NUMBER,
  5    qty_          IN  NUMBER
  6  ) IS
  7     /* What do you need the cursor for? You never fetched from it. If you did, I presume
  8        you might get additional errors (duplicate column names)
  9     CURSOR get_record IS
 10        SELECT *
 11        FROM Supplier_Part_Project_Tab p1, Supplier_Part_Tab p2
 12        WHERE p1.Supplier_Id =supplier_id_ AND p1.Part_Id = part_id_ AND p1.Project_Id =
 13        project_id_ AND p2.Supplier_Id =supplier_id_ AND p2.Part_Id = part_id_;
 14    */
 15  BEGIN
 16    /* Useless, just as cursor itself. BTW, you never fetched from it. If you did,
 17       you'd need a cursor variable (you never declared)
 18    OPEN get_record;
 19    IF get_record%NOTFOUND THEN
 20       dbms_output.Put_Line('No Record found');
 21    END IF;
 22    */
 23    UPDATE supplier_part_project_tab
 24    SET
 25      quantity = quantity + qty_
 26    WHERE supplier_id = supplier_id_
 27          AND part_id = part_id_
 28          AND project_id = project_id_;
 29
 30    UPDATE supplier_part_tab
 31    SET
 32      quantity = quantity - qty_
 33    WHERE supplier_id = supplier_id_
 34          AND part_id = part_id_;
 35
 36    dbms_output.put_line('Record UPDATED');
 37
 38    -- If we don't open it, we don't close it either
 39    -- CLOSE get_record;
 40  END p_isppq;
 41  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing: tables' contents before running the procedure:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM supplier_part_project_tab;

SUPPLIER_ID    PART_ID PROJECT_ID   QUANTITY
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------
          1          1          1        100

SQL> SELECT * FROM supplier_part_tab;

SUPPLIER_ID    PART_ID   QUANTITY
----------- ---------- ----------
          1          1        100
```

Quantity = 20. What happens?

```
SQL> EXEC p_isppq(1, 1, 1, 20);
Record UPDATED

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT * FROM supplier_part_project_tab;

SUPPLIER_ID    PART_ID PROJECT_ID   QUANTITY
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------
          1          1          1        120   --> quantity increased by 20

SQL> SELECT * FROM supplier_part_tab;

SUPPLIER_ID    PART_ID   QUANTITY
----------- ---------- ----------
          1          1         80             --> quantity decreased by 20

SQL>
```